# What's another phrase for "word for word"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, foreign-phrases

It's a sudden random question I have but I distinctly remember there being another phrase, probably of another language, which means exactly the same as "word for word". What is it?

Comment: Word for word: In exactly the same words; verbatim.

Comment: you literally want the literal meaning of literally

Comment: I ordinarily don't like using the "general reference" close reason, but it really does apply here. [See Merriam-Webster's definition of "word for word", for example.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/word%20for%20word) People often don't realize that dictionaries contain many multi-word terms, not just single words.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Verbatim](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/verbatim): (from TFD)

> - using exactly the same words; corresponding word for word: a verbatim report of the conversation.

or literally:

> - in a literal manner; word for word: translated the Greek passage literally.

Comment: Thanks! This was the exact word I'm looking for. I'd somehow forgotten it.

Answer (score 9):

As Joshn61 said, the most common synonym is simply *Verbatim*.

In many contexts you could also replace it with *exactly*. For example:

```
The text was copied word for word.
The text was copied verbatim.
The text was copied exactly.
```

They all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

***And I quote*** Is quite a common way to say it when retelling what someone has said:

> You said to me last week, and I quote, "I will never drink again"